# Return of function in ternary comparison

Tags: javascript, ternary

simple code but answer not found (maybe I haven't looked deep enough since my main language isn't english..)

```
getDeviceInfos(deviceIP) ? displayDevice(**return of getDeviceInfos function**) : dead.push=deviceIP;
```

If `getDeviceInfos` returns something else than `0` (ie. it `== true`), i want the return value to be the argument in `displayDevice` call.

Is there any way to do it or I need to write a "regular" comparison ?
Thanks

Comment: What's your question? It's really hard to tell what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Could you write it out in classic IF statement syntax

Comment: If getDeviceInfos returns something else than 0 (then true), i want the return value to be the argument in displayDevice call

Comment: Also, do you intent to set the `push` property of whatever `dead` is to the `deviceIP`, or is `dead` an array and you want to add `deviceIP` to that array?

Comment: Just use a regular `if...else` construct. IMO you gain nothing by jamming everything into one line.

Comment: @JeanneD4RK if one of the answers helped you, or answered your question, consider marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following, but it would need a var to avoid a global variable. As a result, it's not really a straight expression.

```
var info;
(info = getDeviceInfos(deviceIP)) ? displayDevice(info) : (dead.push = deviceIP);
```

While this wasn't your question, you can (and perhaps should) do something similar by caching the result with a standard `if`-`else` statement, either when you `var info`, or in the `if` itself:

```
var info;
if (info = getDeviceInfos(deviceIP)) {
  displayDevice(info);
} else {
  dead.push = deviceIP;
}
```

Provided you're not using the value produced by the ternary expression, I would recommend the latter approach for readability.

Comment: Yes, you _could_ and I'd say you _should_ use standard if-then syntax!

Answer (score 2):

First create a variable, then perform the assignment and compare like so -

```
var a; // <-- A variable.
(a = getDeviceInfos(deviceIP)) ? displayDevice(a) : dead.push = deviceIP;
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on your update in the comments sections (and for readability's sake), I'd suggest making it a two step check:

```
var deviceInfo = getDeviceInfos(deviceIP);
(deviceInfo !== 0) ? displayDevice(deviceInfo) : dead.push=deviceIP;
```

That is a more accurate check of the condition and is easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

[Conditional Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Multiple ternary evaluations are also possible (note: the conditional operator is right associative).

```
var hadRelations = false;
var isSure = false;
var presidentQuote = hadRelations ? "Had relations" : isSure ? "Did not have relations" : "I admit";
console.log( presidentQuote ); // Prints "I admit" in the console
```

Answer (score 0):

I moved it into the function itself..

```
function getDeviceInfos(pIp)
{
    //code
    result ? displayDevice(result) : dead[dead.length]=pIp
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this isn't strictly speaking an answer your question, but I'd strongly recommend considering *not* using the ternary syntax, ever. When writing code, always balance what is the easiest to read and maintain with what is compact, efficient, and cool.

In practice, ternary syntax isn't significantly faster than an if statement, so there's generally no "efficiency" grounds to use it.

Compare:

```
var info;
(info = getDeviceInfos(deviceIP)) ? displayDevice(info) : (dead.push = deviceIP);
```

with ...

```
var info = getDeviceInfos(deviceIP);
if (info) {
  displayDevice(info);
} else {
  dead.push = deviceIP;
}
```

Sure, the if-then style is less compact, but it's **much easier to understand, debug and extend**.

In short, there's almost never a reason to use ternary syntax: it's generally harmful to code quality. Avoid.

Comment: "generally harmful to code quality" is a pretty bold statement.   LOL